# Как отсортировать список по имени лексикографически

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных

**head.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TEXT_H 
#define TEXT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct FDat {               //структура данных
    char Name[20];          //имя
    char d[8];             //телефон 
    struct FDat *Next;
};

FDat *Add(FDat *, FDat *);
FDat *Del(FDat *, int &);
void Show(FDat *);
void Find(FDat *);
void Findtel(FDat *);
void FreeRam(FDat *);
void Sort(FDat *);
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "head.h"

using namespace std;

FDat *Add(FDat *posl)
{
    if (posl == NULL) {
        posl = new FDat;
    }
    else {
        posl->Next = new FDat;
        posl = posl->Next;
    }

    cout << "Vvedite - Name, Telephone: \n";
    cin >> posl->Name >> posl->d;
    posl->Next = NULL;
    return posl;
}

FDat *Del(FDat *begin, int &identif)
{
    FDat *prom, *begin_new, *next;
    int x = 0, j = 0, k = 0, y = 0;
    char name[20];

    cout << "Deleting \n";

    cout << "Vvedite NAME : ";
    cin >> name;
    begin_new = prom = next = begin;
    while (begin != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(name); i++)
            if (name[i] == begin->Name[i]) j++;
        if (j == strlen(name)) {
            if (prom == begin) {
                begin_new = begin->Next;
                prom = begin->Next;
                delete begin;
                x = 1;
                y = 1;
                begin = prom;
            }
            else {
                while (k == 0) {
                    if (next->Next == begin) {
                        if (next->Next->Next == NULL) {
                            k = 1;
                            x = 1;
                            delete begin;
                            next->Next = NULL;
                            begin = NULL;
                            identif = 1;
                            begin_new = next;
                        }
                        else {
                            prom = begin->Next;
                            delete begin;
                            x = 1;
                            k = 1;
                            y = 1;
                            next->Next = begin = prom;
                        }
                    }
                    next = next->Next;
                }
            }
        }
        if (y == 1) begin = NULL;
        if (begin != NULL)  begin = begin->Next;
        j = 0;
    }
    if (x == 0)
        cout << "No result ";
    _getch();
    return begin_new;

}

void Show(FDat *begin)
{
    cout << "Prosmotr spiska \n";
    cout << "Name - Telephone \n";
    while (begin != NULL) {
        cout << "\n" << begin->Name << " - " << begin->d << " \n ";
        begin = begin->Next;
    }
    _getch();

}

void Sort(FDat *begin)
{
//  Не знаю как отсортировать список
}



void Find(FDat *begin)
{
    int x = 0, j = 0;
    char name[20];
    cout << "Search: \n";
    cout << "Vvedite NAME : ";
    cin >> name;
    while (begin != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(name); i++)
            if (name[i] == begin->Name[i]) j++;

        if (j == strlen(name)) {
            cout << "\n" << begin->Name << " " << begin->d << " \n ";
            x = 1;
            j = 0;
        }

        begin = begin->Next;
    }
    if (x == 0)
        cout << "No result \n ";
    _getch();
}

void Findtel(FDat *begin)
{
    int x = 0, j = 0;
    char tel[8];
    cout << "Search Tel \n";
    cout << "Vvedite Tel : ";
    cin >> tel;
    while (begin != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(tel); i++)
            if (tel[i] == begin->d[i]) j++;

        if (j == strlen(tel)) {
            cout << "\n" << begin->Name << "." << " " << begin->d << " \n ";
            x = 1;
            j = 0;
        }

        begin = begin->Next;
    }
    if (x == 0)
        cout << " No result \n" << endl;
    _getch();
}

void FreeRam(FDat *begin)
{
    FDat *prom;
    cout << " Delete! \n";
    prom = begin;
    while (prom != NULL) {
        begin = begin->Next;
        delete prom;
        prom = begin;
    }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{

    FDat *Begin = NULL, *Posl = NULL, *Dopol;
    int ch, cr, iden = 0;             //   наж. клавиша



    do {
        cout << " <1> - DOBAVIT ZAPIS \n"
             << " <2> - UDALIT ZAPIS \n"
             << " <3> - PROSMOTR SPISKA \n"
             << " <4> - POISK \n"
             << " <5> - EXIT \n";

        cin >> ch;       //  {реализация меню}

        switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            if (Begin == NULL) {
                Begin = Add(Posl);
                Posl = Begin;
            }
            else Posl = Add(Posl);

            break;
        case 2:
            Dopol = Del(Begin, iden);
            if (iden == 0) Begin = Dopol;
            else Posl = Dopol;
            break;
        case 3:
            Show(Begin);
            Sort(Begin);
            break;
        case 4:
            do {
                cout << 
                    " <1> - Poisk po imeni \n" <<
                    " <2> - Poisk po telefony \n" <<
                    " <3> - Exit \n";
                cin >> cr;

                switch (cr) {

                case 1:
                    Find(Begin);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Findtel(Begin);
                    break;
                }

            } while (cr != 3);
        }

    } 
    while (ch != 5);



    FreeRam(Begin);           //   очистка памяти

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас все правильно работает(я не проверял), то может быть такой вариант сортировки:

```
void Sort(FDat *begin)
{
    for (FDat* i = begin;  i ; i = i->Next) {
            FDat* min = i;
            for (FDat* j = i->Next; j; j = j->Next) {
                if (strcmp(i->Name, j->Name) > 0) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }    
            if (min != i) {
                FDat* t  = i;
                i = j;
                j = t;
            }           
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сравнения надо либо использовать библиотечную функцию strcmp, либо написать какую-то свою реализацию на подобии этой:

```
int compare (
            const char * str1,
            const char * str2,
            size_t len1,
            size_t len2
            ) {
    unsigned char *s1 = (unsigned char *) str1;
    unsigned char *s2 = (unsigned char *) str2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len1 && i < len2; i++) {
        if (s1[i] != s2[i]) {
            return (int)s1[i] - (int)s2[i];
        }
    }

    return (int)len1 - (int)len2;
}
```

Затем уже воспользоваться любой из сортировок, в том числе стандартной `qsort`.

Comment: а вы пробовали передавать интрузивный список в qsort?

Answer (score 0):

Собественно, я сделал таким образом, может кому пригодится.

```
    void sort_list(struct FDat*  begin) {
    struct FDat*  first;
    struct FDat*  last;
    int  id, tmp;
    char name[20];
    while (1) {
        id = 0;
        first = begin;
        last = begin->Next;
        for (; last != NULL; last = last->Next, first = first->Next) {

            if ((tolower(first->Name[0]) > tolower(last->Name[0]))) {
                strcpy_s(name, first->Name);
                strcpy_s(first->Name, last->Name);
                strcpy_s(last->Name, name);


                id |= 1;
            }
        }
        if (!id)
            break;

    };

    cout << "Prosmotr spiska \n";
    cout << "Name - Telephone \n";
    while (begin != NULL) {
        cout << "\n" << begin->Name << " - " << begin->d << " \n ";
        begin = begin->Next;
    }
    _getch();
}
```